# Extend ProposalProvider in external Eclipse Project via Extension Point

Tags: eclipse-rcp, xtext

I try to extend my MyDSLProposalProvider from an external Eclipse RCP Project. I created an extension point schema which requires a class property which extends my ProposalProvider. In the new project I extend the class an overrode some methods justs to give me some output so I can see that the external method is called. But this is currently not happening. Is there anything I have to consider?

Currently the hirachy looks like:

```
MyDSLProposalProvider extends AbstractMyDSLProposalProvider  
ExternalProposalProvider extends MyDSLProposalProvider
```

I rewrote a Method generated in the `AbstractMyDSLProposalProvider` but when its triggered the predefined Method in the `AbstractMyDSLProposalProvider` is called and not my new implementation.

```java
    public class ExternalMyDSLProposalPovider extends MyDSLProposalProvider
    {
    @Override
   public void completeComponent_Name(EObject model, Assignment 
   assignment, ContentAssistContext context,
        ICompletionProposalAcceptor acceptor) {
    System.err.println("extern");
    if(model instanceof Component)
    {
        createProposal("foo", "foo", context, acceptor);
    }
    super.completeComponent_Name(model, assignment, context, acceptor);
    }
    }
```

This is the class in the external `Eclipse Project`. 
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Is the new project actually declaring an extension point using your new schema?  How are you dealing with reading the extension point definitions in your main plugin?

Comment: Yes the new project declares an extension for the provided extension point of myDSL project.. But I don't get the second part of your question. Can you maybe exlplain what you mean with some more details?

Comment: If you define a new extension point with a schema you must write code to read the extension points that use that schema from the `IExtensionRegistry`- have you done that?

Comment: No I haven't. But it seems that this is the problem here. Is there a spot where I have to register my extension or is this already in the registry but I have to call it when I want to trigger, or how does it work? Sry for the stupid question, I havent done this before. And thanks already, at least I know where I have to look into.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you declare an extension point using a schema that you have defined Eclipse puts that declaration in the extension point registry. That is all that is does, you must then write code to make uses of those declarations.

You read the extension point registry using something like:

```java
IExtensionRegistry extRegistry = Platform.getExtensionRegistry();

IExtensionPoint extPoint = extRegistry.getExtensionPoint("your extension point id");

IConfigurationElement [] elements = extPoint.getConfigurationElements();
```

`elements` is now an array of the declarations in the various plugins using the extension point.

`IConfigurationElement` has various methods to get the values of the attributes of the declaration.

If you have defined a class in one of the attributes you can create an instance of the class using:

```java
IConfigurationElement element =  .... a config element

Object obj = element.createExecutableExtension("attribute name");
```

In your case the result should be your `ExternalMyDSLProposalPovider`.

You will then need to hook this object up with whatever is doing to proposals.